# EXCEL 2010: INDEX/MATCH dropping cell formatting (Accounting & $$)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program:** Excel 2010
**Experience:** Basic

Issue:
I am using INDEX/MATCH
This is the original cell which resolves to:
1)  1.0692 (exchange rate)
2)  147.50 (exch * value)
3)  $39.99 (prod cost)
4)  Ex: 1.0692 SubT: 147.5046936

```
=INDEX(ssExchRate,MATCH(A33,ssRepDist,0))  
=" SubT: " &INDEX(ssExchST4,MATCH(A33,ssRepDist,0))  
=INDEX(ssUnitPr,MATCH(A33,ssRepDist,0))  
="Ex: "&INDEX(ssExchRate,MATCH(A33,ssRepDist,0)) & " SubT: " &INDEX(ssExchST4,MATCH(A33,ssRepDist,0))
```

To be able to get $ or - (for discounts) I need to use:

```
="-$"&INDEX(ssBankAU,MATCH(A33,ssRepDist,0))
```

Is there a way for the formula to retain cell information, or do I have to hardcode it like my final example?

Cheers.

Comment: you can create [custom format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx)

Comment: @simoco Thank you. It didn't work for all of the cells, I think the ones where it's mixed text & numbers it was having issues with.  `4) Ex: 1.0692 SubT: 147.5046936` is the main one. I can't split the cells as I have limited space.  Thanks anyway :)  My OCD will have to cope. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misundestood your question, you have `Ex: 1.0692 SubT: 147.5046936` in single cell. In that case only `"-$"&INDEX(..)`

Comment: @simoco Sadly that is what I thought :)  I'll make my OCD deal with that.
Can you please make that your official answer and I will accept it :)  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `TEXT` formula.

```
=TEXT(INDEX(ssBankAU,MATCH(A33,ssRepDist,0)),"-$#,##0.00)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Follow up from comments.*

For cases 1,3 you can apply custom format like in image below:

[image]

For case 2:

[image]

Unfortunatelly for case 4, you should use your original formula.